# Reading a txt file to Pandas with no identified delimiter

Tags: python, pandas, csv, txt

I'm trying to read a text file to Python using Pandas. I have struggled trying to identify how the file is delimited and read it.
The txt file is organized like this:
[Summary.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PugAa.png)

```
Date: 9/10/2021 1:53:38 AM.  Run ID: 115756


Fixture: 1 (COM 51)
-------------------

Position    Serial      Fail reason

1:      0811010750
2:      0811010240
3:      0811009324
4:      0811009130
5:      0811010032
6:      0811010082
7:      0811009366
8:      0811009247
9:      0811010170
10:                 FAILED SCAN
11:         0811009938
12:         0811009532
13:         0811009299
14:         0811009995  CO2 Stability
```

I tried to read it using the next code:

```
import pandas as pd

summary = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\eduardo.romero\Documents\VSC_TXT\Summary.txt", skiprows=0,
                               header = None , delim_whitespace=True, )
```

print(summary)

Giving the next result:

```
                       0           1         2       3    4    5         6
0                  Date:   4/11/2021  12:46:08     AM.  Run  ID:  105952.0
1               Fixture:           1      (COM     51)  NaN  NaN       NaN
2    -------------------         NaN       NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
3               Position      Serial      Fail  reason  NaN  NaN       NaN
4                     1:  0811007101       NaN     NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
..                   ...         ...       ...     ...  ...  ...       ...
303                  72:      FAILED      SCAN     NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
304                  73:      FAILED      SCAN     NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
305                  74:      FAILED      SCAN     NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
306                  75:      FAILED      SCAN     NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN
307                  76:      FAILED      SCAN     NaN  NaN  NaN       NaN

[308 rows x 7 columns]
```

What I'm trying to do is to read it as Excel would format the file:
[Excel data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fj3x9.png)

Thank you for your help!

EDIT: RUNNING WITH FWF
[pf.read_fwf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWZv6.png)

Result:

```
    Position\tSerial\t\tFail reason
0                 1: \t\t0811007101
1                 2: \t\t0811007303
2                 3: \t\t0811007300
3                 4: \t\t0811007312
4                 5: \t\t0811007139
..                              ...
299         72: \t\t\t\tFAILED SCAN
300         73: \t\t\t\tFAILED SCAN
301         74: \t\t\t\tFAILED SCAN
302         75: \t\t\t\tFAILED SCAN
303         76: \t\t\t\tFAILED SCAN

[304 rows x 1 columns]
```

Comment: i think you want https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `read_fwf` and skip some initial lines:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_fwf('input.txt', skiprows=5, keep_default_na=False)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   Position      Serial    Fail reason
0        1:  0811010750               
1        2:  0811010240               
2        3:  0811009324               
3        4:  0811009130               
4        5:  0811010032               
5        6:  0811010082               
6        7:  0811009366               
7        8:  0811009247               
8        9:  0811010170               
9       10:                FAILED SCAN
10      11:  0811009938               
11      12:  0811009532               
12      13:  0811009299               
13      14:  0811009995  CO2 Stability
```

Comment: Mark, I just updated the question with the result that I get when running fwf, do you know what it cause it? Thank you!

Comment: @EduardoRomero You have tab delimiters instead of spaces